# Play bg video on close Fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have video on bg and button for open this video in popup Fancybox
I need when I open video in Fancybox popup video on bg is paused and when I close this popup video on bg is play
I tried this code but it works on the second attempt to close the popup
Fancybox ver 5.0

```
        const video = document.querySelector('.hero-section__video-bg video'),
            videoPlayBtn = document.querySelector('.hero-section__video-btn')

        videoPlayBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            video.pause()
        })

        window.addEventListener('click', function () {
            Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="video"]', {
                on: {
                    close: (fancybox, eventName) => {
                        video.play()
                    },
                }
            })
        })
```

[Link to demo](https://test.andygroove.com/toothbrush/)

Comment: Please add reproducible example. Also mention which version of fancybox you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need window click handler.
Fancy box event handler will kick in when you click on close button.
So this would work.

```
const video = document.querySelector('.hero-section__video-bg video'),
  videoPlayBtn = document.querySelector('.hero-section__video-btn')

videoPlayBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.pause()
})

Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="video"]', {
  on: {
    close: (fancybox, eventName) => {
      video.play()
    },
  }
});
```